# Inaccessible socket behind counter needed for washing machine

Tags: washing-machine, socket, cord-and-plug

I’m trying to fit my washing machine and the only socket for it is in an inaccessible spot on the wall behind the cabinet next to the washing machine gap. The gap is very small, only enough to fit your arm in there just about and no space to actually push the plug in. There was a washing machine there before but I don’t know how they got the plug in or out.

How do I access it?

[image]

Comment: So move the cabinet, plug it in, and put the cabinet back?

Comment: Hole drills are wonderful things. You'll never see it once everything is back in place.

Comment: @PeteCon care to expand on that?

Answer (score 3):

I would have put an opening in the back of the cupboard so that the cable can be passed through the gap and then easily plugged in.

Another option is to have a "short" length plug or "right-angle" plug that can be fitted.

Comment: See that’s what I thought but the people who lived here before already had a washing machine plugged in and unplugged it with having a hole so how did they do that?

Comment: Generally speaking (in the US, at least) @Alice, large appliance cords (washer, dryer, stove, etc.) are replaceable with just a screwdriver. Go buy a new cord that has the right-angle end. It's far thinner and you'll be able to squeeze it into place. Make sure you get a cord to match the receptacle (3-prong if necessary, 4-prong preferable and more safe). You _could_ measure back to the receptacle, then cut your own access hole in the cupboard back, then push the cord behind and plug it in from inside the cupboard. Just because the previous owner struggled doesn't mean you _have_ to.